# replace() tag did not work in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, database

I have database, that currently use inline edit in tables
First problem was with paste of formatted text, but seems, that problem was fixed at 90% with this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                var _onPaste_StripFormatting_IEPaste = false;

                function OnPaste_StripFormatting(elem, e) {

                    if (e.originalEvent && e.originalEvent.clipboardData && e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var text = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
                        window.document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
                    }
                    else if (e.clipboardData && e.clipboardData.getData) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var text = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
                        window.document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
                    }
                    else if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.getData) {
                        // Stop stack overflow
                        if (!_onPaste_StripFormatting_IEPaste) {
                            _onPaste_StripFormatting_IEPaste = true;
                            e.preventDefault();
                            window.document.execCommand('ms-pasteTextOnly', false);
                        }
                        _onPaste_StripFormatting_IEPaste = false;
                    }

                }

    </script>
```

My php code look like this:

```
<td contenteditable='true' onblur=saveToDatabase(this,'titleeng','".$data['id']."') onClick='showEdit(this);' onpaste='OnPaste_StripFormatting(this, event);'>".$data['titleeng']."</td>
```

The script removes the tags, but leaves the `&nbsp;` , that causing my sql ajax to failure

Here is Ajax script:

```
<script>
        function showEdit(editableObj) {
            $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF");
        } 

        function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
            $(editableObj).css("background","#12ff65 url(loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");
            $.ajax({
                url: "saveedit.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:"column="+column+"&editval="+editableObj.innerHTML+"&id="+id,
                success: function(data){
                    $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
                }        
           });
        }
        </script>
```

I am trying this:
New components are `text = text.replace("&nbsp"," ");`

```
var _onPaste_StripFormatting_IEPaste = false;

                function OnPaste_StripFormatting(elem, e) {

                    if (e.originalEvent && e.originalEvent.clipboardData && e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var text = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
                        string text = text;
                        text = text.replace("&nbsp"," ");
                        window.document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
                    }
                    else if (e.clipboardData && e.clipboardData.getData) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var text = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
                        string text = text;
                        text = text.replace("&nbsp"," ");
                        window.document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
                    }
                    else if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.getData) {
                        // Stop stack overflow
                        if (!_onPaste_StripFormatting_IEPaste) {
                            _onPaste_StripFormatting_IEPaste = true;
                            e.preventDefault();
                            window.document.execCommand('ms-pasteTextOnly', false);
                        }
                        _onPaste_StripFormatting_IEPaste = false;
                    }

                }
```

But nothing

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/subsa/79dr2grn/ Did not replace even first nbsp. Paste text from CSS, there are hidden nbsp

Answer (score 1):

> The script removes the tags, but leaves the `&nbsp;` , that causing my sql ajax to failure

That‘s because you neglected to URL-encode the parameter values you insert into the query string properly.

Use `encodeURIComponent` on the values before.

Comment: I have a try, but return me value with %3 %2 etc, after save show it properly, except the breaks dissapear

Comment: _"but return me value with %3 %2 etc"_ - yeah, that’s what URL percent encoding _is_. _"after save show it properly, except the breaks dissapear"_ - that should have nothing whatsoever to do with the URL encoding, but is more likely an issue with how you output the data. But you would need to be more specific on what you actually mean here, if you want help figuring this out.

Comment: @pete: no, the URL encoding does not have to be reversed - that has happened already by the time you access the parameter values in PHP.

Comment: No, completely the wrong place. I was talking about your AJAX request - that is the place where you _put_ values into the URL context (by inserting them into the query string), and therefor that is the place where you have to properly URL-encode the values first.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ybLLag2p/2/ in CSS is the script with hidden nbsp in each line after first

Comment: Yeah I think need to switch some other method, not ajax post

Comment: If we able to clean the &xxx; codes, will make it work as well, I hope

Comment: Seems I do not know how to do it. I have tried some options, but not.

Answer (score 0):

finally problem was with encoding as CBroe says

here is the ajax, that make it work

```
function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
            $(editableObj).css("background","#12ff65 url(loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");
            var editxx = encodeURIComponent(editableObj.innerHTML);
            $.ajax({
                url: "saveedit.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:"column="+column+"&editval="+editxx+"&id="+id,
                success: function(data){
                    $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
                }        
           });
        }
```